# How to print mean NPP value from MODIS imagery in my area of interest

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am a beginner in using Google Earth Engine. I want to know the net primary producticity for the region of Nan (area of interest) in Thailand. From the resources available, I came up with the codes as follows. It only gives me the visualisation and I can inspect the GPP, however is there a possibility I can print out the mean value of NPP over this landscape?
I first imported npp, gpp and Nan data.

```
//set location and zoom level
Map.centerObject(Nan,4);

//add layer
Map.addLayer(Nan,false, "table");

// Define period
var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2021,1,1);
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2022,12,30);

//filter npp
var nppCollection = npp.filterDate(startdate, enddate)
                       .filterBounds(Nan)
                       .select("Npp");
                      
              
//filter gpp
var gppCollection = gpp.filterDate(startdate, enddate)
                       .filterBounds(Nan)
                       .select("Gpp");
//calculate npp8
var myNpp = function(myimg){
  //get date
     var d = ee.Date(myimg.get('system:time_start'))
  //get date
     var y = d.get('year').toInt();
     
  //filter for year for GPP and NPP
     var GPPy = ee.Image(gppCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year')).sum());
     var NPPy = ee.Image(nppCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year')).mean());
     var npp8 = myimg.expression('(GGP8 / GPPy) * NPPy',
    {
        GGP8: myimg,
        GPPy: GPPy,
        NPPy: NPPy
    });
     
  return npp8.copyProperties(myimg,['system:time_start'])
}

var npp8Collection = ee.ImageCollection(gppCollection.map(myNpp));

//create visualtion settings
var npp_viz = {min:0.0, max:300, palette:"ff0000, f0ff00, 004717"};

//add the image
Map.addLayer(npp8Collection.mean().clip(Nan),npp_viz,"npp")
```

Comment: Include the complete script, please, including the definition of your collections. Which exact collections you're using matters. You can also include a link to the script in the Earth Engine Code Editor - use the `Get Link` button.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/c19e9b5d4bc4050abe593e916a6b0e03

Comment: You haven't shared your asset: `projects/ee-mamtalama/assets/Nan_dissolved`